How to use Java Springboot JpaRepository to load mapped relation data dynamically based on the necessity?
I am very new to the Java Springboot framework. I've followed several tutorials and discovered that each time I make an HTTP request to the server, the JpaRepository will return the entity with all its mapped relations.
Here is the code
@Table(name = "provinces")
public class Province {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    private List<City> cities;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    private List<PreRelease> preReleases;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    private List<Project> projects;
}

@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    private Province province;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private List<Project> projects;
}

public class Project {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "province_id")
    private Province province;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id")
    private City city;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "pre_release_id")
    private PreRelease preRelease;
}

My question is that: can JpaRepository load the relation data dynamically, sometimes I do want its mapped relations, and sometimes I don't want its mapped relation data.
any help will be appreciated!

first of all. the related entities are only loaded if you try to access them, because you defined fetch = FetchType.LAZY in your relations
furthermore it depends on what you mean by relations. if you mean that you want to load only the id of the related entities and not the whole entity, i would suggest something like this (IMPORTANT RECORDS ARE AVAILABLE SINCE JAVA 17):
@Query(SELECT new com.baeldung.jpa.records.ProjectRecord(p.id, p.province.id, p.city.id, p.preRelease.id) FROM Project p WHERE b.id = :id") 
ProjectRecord findProjectById(@Param("id") Long id);

using this annotation in the repository with only select the ids and write it to a seperate model, so it doesn't load all rlated entities. if this doesn't work maybe try using a nativeQuery=true in @Query and switching from the JPQL Query to native SQL :)
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-jpa-java-records

Thanks, Thomas. Sometimes I want to load the entity with its specific relational data, and sometimes I don't want to load the entity's relational data. Corresponding to your reply, I need to create a method for each type of data, if a car has a tire and wheel, there will be three methods. Method 1: retrieve data from the database for a car with the tire. Method 2: a car with wheels,. Method 3: a car with tire and wheels.

exactly :) i hope i could help
